# Blur part of image on smartphone webviews

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am currently working on a mobile application in IONIC, and to follow our design specifications, I need to blur some parts of images. My problem is that all the solutions we found work more or less well on browser (Chrome) but not on the webview of android.
The backdrop-filter does not work and the technique using the pseudo-element: before does not work anymore in Android.

The two solutions that I tried and which works partially on chrome are :

#### Solution 1 (backdrop-filter)

```
<style>
body{
 background-image: url("../../assets/img/yosemite.jpg");
}

.blurred-bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height : 120px;
  box-shadow : 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@supports ((backdrop-filter: blur(10px))) or (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px)) {
    .blurred-bg {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }
}
</style>

<body>
     <ion-card id="box1" class="box blurred-bg tinted">
      <ion-card-content class="content">
        <h1>Blurred Background</h1>
        <h2>By Ariona, Rian</h2>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</body>
```

This solution works fine on chrome (execpt on border, but it's ok), but the blurred is not applied on android webview (with the Ionic app). The MDN doc says that the backdrop-filter property is not yet supported on android webview. So I guess that this solution won't be the good one.

---

#### Solution 2 (using the :before pseudo-element on .blurred-bg elements):

```
<style>
body{
 background-image: url("../../assets/img/yosemite.jpg");
}

.blurred-bg {
  height : 120px;
  box-shadow : 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.blurred-bg:before{
  content : '';
  background: url("../../assets/img/yosemite.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size : cover;
  filter : blur(10px);
  position : absolute;
  top : -20px;
  left : -20px;
  right : -20px;
  bottom : -20px;
}
</style>

<body>
     <ion-card id="box1" class="box blurred-bg tinted">
      <ion-card-content class="content">
        <h1>Blurred Background</h1>
        <h2>By Ariona, Rian</h2>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</body>
```

This solution works fine on chrome but is a little bit laggy when I scroll. On the android webview, it's still laggy and the blurred background-image is badly resized and is always at the same position even when I scroll.

---

The background image, which will be blurred on some parts of the screen will be different for each case. And the number of blurred elements on a page won't be always the same (for most of the case there will be only one)

[This is an example of what I try to reproduce on smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC24k.png)

---

Would someone have a solution using Html-css or eventually JS?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to produce the code that you've tried so far in order for someone to help you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yeah can you be more specific and share those design specs? how many images, format? are they shown in slides or?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I changed the description to be more specific.